# How to override/replace 404,500,502 http status page via JavaScript

Tags: javascript, overriding, http-status-code-404, http-status-codes

Any way to replace 404 page via JavaScript? I don't want to have default 500 or 502 page (if server is down) of let's take as an example: shopify or zenddesk (just an example, never tried those companies).

Is it possible to do it or I must use their default status pages?

Comment: Since your JavaScript (most likely) runs in a web page, you would need to serve up a page containing said JavaScript. In short, dealing with status codes has to happen on the server.

Comment: I think, it's possible only if you use AJAX style calls everywhere. If you have traditional web pages with links (href) and forms, I can't imagine what you can possibly do in Java script.